# How to accept the use of cookies programmatically?

Tags: java, android, html, cookies

I have been trying to parse websites with JSOUP on Android in order to extract all the images stored in the HTML. The problem I have come across is that some websites ask you to explicitly accept the use of cookies before you can browse further. When parsing the HTML of those websites, i only get the HTML of the window that asks you to accept the cookie but since I am doing this from code I have no idea how to accept the cookie or how to work around it.

is this even possible?

For example, the website http://tweakers.net. When i parse it with the following:

```
        try {
            //Connect to the website and get the html
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(uri).get();

            //Get all elements with img tag ,
            Elements img = doc.getElementsByTag("img");

            for (Element el : img) {
                //for each element get the srs url
                String src = el.absUrl("src");
                logger.e("image found: " + src);
                //getImages(src);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("There was an error");
            logger.e(ex.getMessage());
        }
```

The only output I get is:

```
image found: http://tweakimg.net/g/cookies/logo-50x50.png
```

which is the image on the little window asking you to accept the use of cookies

So my question is: Is is possible to parse the real website even with this cookie stuff and how do I do it? 
If possible I would like to know a unisersal way to apply to every possible website. Because as far as I have seen, most posts about cookie handling are for specific websites and they include creating the cookie that the website is asking for but this would be a big problem as different websites implement their cookie in different ways.

USE CASE:
this process starts when a user is browsing the web on his phone and then clicks the share button. The intent starts my app, i get the url of the to-be-shared website and i parse it with jsoup.

Comment: Why not using a webbrowser in the background ? It can enable you use cookies

Comment: @Kilanny   hmmm,, so opening a webview in the background could solve the problem? I could definitely try that!

Comment: @Kilanny, if OP's only interaction with the site is via JSoup, how will opening a browser make any difference?

Comment: @AndrewRegan I am not sure.. am quite new to this but the user is first surfing the web using his normal browser e.g. google chrome and then decided to share the page and clicks share and opens my app.. I then fetch the HTML from the website but when I do that it asks to accept the use of cookies again so the HTML that i get is from the popup window.

Comment: How does this page handle you accepting the cookies ? Does it set a cookie to signal this ? If yes simulate this cookie. If you analyze that site you will see that it sets a `TnetID` cookie. Try to mimic that.

Comment: @Marged  I am not quite sure,, but if i would take this aproach I would have a big problem because I am trying to get all the images from the given website and that could be ANY url on which the user is surfing. Some websites (AFAIK only Dutch websites do this) ask explicitly for your conformation on using cookies. Those are simple publuic websites even, no logon required or anything.

Comment: There are many sites that do this, even international ones. I expect that once you set the "marker" (presumably a cookie in this case) _any_ URL on this server can be accessed without being asked again.

Comment: @Marged yes but is it possible to deny or accept the using-cookies-request codewise?

Comment: Yes, it is. But you are searching for a way to accept, aren't you ?

Comment: @Marged indeedy,, I read somewhere that it could be possible with HttpClient,, so I am looking into that right now

Comment: Your already received an answer which tells you how to handle cookies with JSoup ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103130/discussion-between-cantthinkofanything-and-marged).

Comment: @Marged just to clarify, I am indeed looking for a way to accept thje "use cookie request".. But i am trying to find out if its possible to do it for any website... most posts i see are only about handling one type of cookie for one website.. for example login to facebook with cookie or whatever.. I need a way for every website.. dont know if thats possible?

Comment: You can try to Interpret the page and simulate whatever button is there to click, supporting various languages. Difficult ... What happens if you open the page with an useragent similar to a webcrawler ?

Comment: @Marged hmmm opening the page like a webcrawler. Ill check that one out.

Comment: @Marged it works!! I am using the GoogleBot agent though,,, Am i even allowed to do that?

Comment: I don't think Google will sue you over this ;-) But you can try other crawlers or even define your own. Depends on how the sites work: do they detect browsers and only open the special page for them or do they detect Google ?

Comment: @Marged thats the next question indeed,,, ill let you know :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are solving a problem that was only created while protecting the privacy of invidual persons. The site(s) you are connecting to try to inform a person and try to get their consent.

On the other side I think these sites don't want to keep crawlers from finding and indexing their pages.

Try to set a `User-Agent` that signals anything different from the common browsers. That might already do.
If this does not work try to mimic a certain webcrawler, like that of Google, BING or perhaps send the same headers as curl.

Answer (score 2):

There are [lots of answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsoup+cookies) for how to configure JSoup to pass cookies to a target site, once you have determined (manually) what the cookie should look like.

[Cookie to log in with Jsoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9890928/954442) may be the simplest

However, beyond the simplest cases of site-interaction - and given you're already coding in Java - you might consider investigating [Selenium WebDriver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)#Selenium_WebDriver). In which case you would be interacting with the site using a real browser, rather than a HTTP library with its own cookie store, which is what JSoup is built on top of.

Comment: I will definitely check out this Selenium WebDriver. I do have to add though that this "Accepting the use of cookies" is for public websites with no logon required.. So i am not sure what is exactly even happening when i accept the use of cookies

Comment: A site could use cookie checks in all sorts of ways, it depends on the site. It may used cookie-based authentication, so once you've logged in manually and seen the cookies created, you can pass them to JSoup or any other HTTP library. I'm just trying to answer your original question. Perhaps you need to create a new one or do some experimentation first?

Comment: yes, maybe i do need to create a new question.. Thanks!

Comment: OK, hope this answer has helped anyway.

Comment: Well, now I do know where to look for information on handling cookies hehe. The Selenium webdriver might also be of some use as it can send commands to a website.. Ill have to see how to solve my problem.. I dont even know what my problem exactly is hehe.. Thanks for taking the time to help me though,, I apreciate the efforts of this community a lot!