# Jsoup library in Java - logging on Google

Tags: java, eclipse, cookies, gmail, jsoup

The question is just how should I write my code to receive just one cookie, which I could use for connecting to websites that require logging in?

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("https://gmail.com")
        .data(<all stuff for logging in>)
        .execute();
```

And `res.cookies()` would give me my session ID etc.

Comment: Maybe this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890928/cookie-to-log-in-in-jsoup help

Comment: One more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432970/jsoup-posting-and-cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this:

```
  String loginUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/Login?hl=pl#identifier";
  Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect(loginUrl)
          .data("Email", MYMAIL)
          .execute();

  Connection.Response res2 = Jsoup.connect(loginUrl)
          .cookies(res.cookies())
          .data("Passwd", MYPASS)
          .execute();


  Document page = Jsoup
            .connect("https://adwords.google.com/")
            .cookies(res2.cookies()) 
            .get();

  System.out.println(page.toString());
```

And I don't see the page I want to see. Propably this shouldn't be working but I can't code anything better yet. It worked on t

Basically, my main target is to be able to extract data from AdWords using Java (I'm working with Eclipse). The last obstacle is logging in.